# How to map array response coming from the api using redux in react js in react js.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image: Here you can see my api response]Iam trying to map a array of objects in my react js app i am getting my response using redux which is true the problem is whenever iam using `mapstatetoprops` and `mapDispatchtoprops` it is not mapping my props into the state due to which iam getting undefined in my console other than that iam unable to map nested array response i want to get value which is inside of `inputOptions` how can i fix these issues. [image: this the response of correcting it to getForms: data.categories.forms,]

My component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  FormCardComponent,
  TextInputComponent,
  RadioInputComponent,
  SelectComponent,
} from "../../components/index";
import IntlMessages from "../../common/constants/IntlMessages";
import frontPage from "./dummy";
import { TopBar } from "../../layouts/authLayout/components/index";
import { getEmsForms } from "../../redux/action/categories";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Form } from "./form";

class DummyForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      field: "",
      checkBox: "",
      options: "",
      radioField: "",
      error: "",
      data: frontPage,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getEmsForms()
  }

  render() {
    console.log('COMP',JSON.stringify(this.props.getEmsForms()));

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="col" style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
          <React.Fragment>
            <TextInputComponent
              style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}
              label={<IntlMessages id="profile.personal.field.name" />}
              type="text"
              placeholder={"Abdul"}
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={(e) =>
                this.setState({ name: e.target.value, error: "" })
              }
            />
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              id="inputGroupSelect01"
              style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}
            >
              <option>
                {/* {value.MinimumAge} */}
                yes
              </option>
              <option>
                {/* {value.MinimumAge} */}
                yes
              </option>
            </select>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
              <SelectComponent
                style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}
                name={"select2"}
                value={this.state.select2}
                label={
                  "Jeg vil gerne modtage en SMS når der er nyheder til mig"
                }
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({ select2: e.target.checked })}
              />
            </div>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
              {/* <RadioInputComponent
                  title="gender"
                  value={this.state.gender}
                  name={["male", "female", "other"]}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ gender: e.target.value, error: "" });
                  }}
                /> */}
              <input
                style={{
                  float: "left",
                  clear: "none",
                  margin: "3px",
                }}
                type="radio"
              />
              <label style={{ padding: " 0px 1em 0px 8px" }}>
                Jeg vil gerne modtage en SMS når der er nyheder til mig
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
              <div className="col d-flex justify-content-start">
                <button className="btn-danger" onClick={this.toggleModal}>
                  Ja
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                <button className="btn btn-success button-margin">Ja</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (data) => ({
  // user: data.authenticateUser.user,
  // isAuthenticated: data.authUser,
  getForms: data.categories.getForms,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      getEmsForms,
    },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DummyForm);
```

My Api Response

```
{
 "success": true,
 "messages": "EMS Form",
 "data": [
  {
   "question_id": 3,
   "fieldName": "FirstName",
   "order": 0,
   "isRequired": true,
   "isShown": true,
   "isEditable": false,
   "fieldLabelText": "First Name da",
   "errorText": "First Name Error da",
   "inputType": "textbox",
   "inputOptions": [],
   "inputOptionsCustom": []
  },
  {
   "question_id": 4,
   "fieldName": "LastName",
   "order": 1,
   "isRequired": true,
   "isShown": true,
   "isEditable": false,
   "fieldLabelText": "First Name da",
   "errorText": "First Name Error da",
   "inputType": "textbox",
   "inputOptions": [],
   "inputOptionsCustom": []
  },
  {
   "question_id": 2,
   "fieldName": "Age",
   "order": 2,
   "isRequired": true,
   "isShown": true,
   "isEditable": false,
   "fieldLabelText": "First Name da",
   "errorText": "First Name Error da",
   "inputType": "dropdown",
   "inputOptions": [
    {
     "option_id": 7,
     "text": "18",
     "value": "18"
    },
    {
     "option_id": 8,
     "text": "19",
     "value": "19"
    },
    {
     "option_id": 9,
     "text": "20",
     "value": "20"
    },
    {
     "option_id": 10,
     "text": "21",
     "value": "21"
    },
    {
     "option_id": 11,
     "text": "22",
     "value": "22"
    },
    {
     "option_id": 12,
     "text": "23",
     "value": "23"
    }
   ],
   "inputOptionsCustom": []
  },
  {
   "question_id": 5,
   "fieldName": "PhoneNumber",
   "order": 3,
   "isRequired": false,
   "isShown": true,
   "isEditable": false,
   "fieldLabelText": "First Name da",
   "errorText": "First Name Error da",
   "inputType": "textbox",
   "inputOptions": [],
   "inputOptionsCustom": []
  }
 ]
}
```

my action

```
export const getEmsForms = (data) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fullScreenLoader(true));
    const api = new Axios();
    let token = getToken();
    console.log('token', JSON.stringify(token))
    const response = await api.post(
      GET_EMS_FORMS,
      {
        ems_id: EMS_ID,
      },
      {
       Authorization:  `Bearer ${token}`,
      },API_URL2
    );
    // console.log(response);
    console.log('res', JSON.stringify(response))
    const { data } = response;
    dispatch(fullScreenLoader(false));
    dispatch({
      type: GET_FORMS ,
      payload: data,
    });
  };
};
```

my reducer

```
case GET_FORMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        forms: action,
      };
```

Comment: for the case of `GET_FORMS` you seem to put the value of `action` in the property `forms` but in the `mapsStateToProps` you are accessing `data.categories.getForms`. Shouldn't you be accessing the `forms` part of your state?

Comment: also, there's no JSX where you're trying to use `map`.

Comment: @RameshReddy can you give me a solution to this problem

Comment: Can you answer my questions above? You're just accessing incorrect properties.

Comment: I have corrected it and now iam getting response `getForms: data.categories.forms,`

Comment: @RameshReddy https://i.stack.imgur.com/3akPP.png this is the response after correcting it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `data.categories.getForms`, but in your reducer you are mapping it to `forms`. Also you want to set the `action.payload` to `.forms` and not the whole action.

So you reducer needs to look like this:

```
case GET_FORMS:
  return {
    ...state,
    forms: action.payload,
  };
```

and your `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = (data) => ({
  user: data.authenticateUser.user,
  isAuthenticated: data.authUser,
  forms: data.categories.forms,
});
```

Comment: this will add a `forms` property to the component props but it is still pointing to `data.categories.getForms` so, this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: iam not getting any data in my `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: Ah sorry, that was something I missed after copy-pasting the snippet